# Factory Girl sequence fails under autospec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, factory-bot

I have this Factory:

```
Factory.define :email_address do |e|
  e.sequence(:address) { |n| "factory_#{n}@example.com" }
  e.validated true
end
```

When I run my specs with `rake spec`, it works fine.

When I run autospec, it fails right away, claiming that the email address is being used twice in two different objects (there is a validation which restricts this).

Why is it behaving differently under autospec?

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, when you abort a test suite with Ctrl+C, it may leave your database dirty. As your database is dirty, creating new objects is going to have validation conflicts. Just run `rake db:test:clone` again and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what is happening is that FactoryGirl is resetting that `n` on each invocation from `autospec`, but the database hasn't been emptied.

First, to check this diagnosis, change your factory to the following:

```
Factory.define :email_address do |e|
  e.sequence(:address) { |n| puts "Email ##{n}"; "factory_#{n}@example.com" }
  e.validated true
end
```

If my diagnosis is correct, there are two possible fixes:

1. change FactoryGirl to start from an index greater than the maximum ID used. This would involve some serious hacking on `Factory::Sequence` - you would probably have to turn `Factory::Sequence.sequences` from a `Hash[Symbol => Proc]` to a `Hash[Symbol => [Proc, Integer]` that remembered the highest index it used. Indeed, that might not even work since autospec *does* seem to be unloading the FactoryGirl classes properly (otherwise the sequence lookup wouldn't be failing and creating a new `Factory::Sequence` object).
2. figure out why your database isn't being cleared between each autospec run. Have you checked your teardown methods? Does your testing database support transactions?

Comment: It has since started working again. Since I wrote the question I've upgraded a bunch of gems and my codebase has changed a lot. I really couldn't even guess what the problem was.

Thanks for your input! If I have similar problems in the future I'll have a troubleshooting starting point.

Peace
John